# How can i recursively move files multiple times with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run 2 different commands in 1 script.

I basically want to move files older than 10 minutes to a backup folder, then in the backup folder, if the file is over 14 days, i want it to be automatically deleted.

I want this to be running immediately as the computer starts up, so I'm using task scheduler to run it.

Currently, I've tried to write the codes together, but it doesn't seem to run all the code.

The code to move the files:

```
while ($true) {
  get-childitem -Path "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Powershell-test" -recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -le (get-date).AddMinutes(-1)}|  move-item -destination "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Powershell--transfer" -force; 
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

The code to delete the files:

```
while ($true) {
  Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Remove' -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime.Date -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-14))} |  Remove-Item
}
```

I'd like all of this to run from one script as one code.

Comment: Why not just use `robocopy`?

Comment: If it's *"not running all of the code"* then we likely need to see what is setting your while loop.  I don't believe you even need a loop of a `while` against a `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine commands in while body.

```
while ($true) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Powershell-test" -recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -le (get-date).AddMinutes(-1)}| move-item -destination "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Powershell--transfer" -force; 
    Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Powershell--transfer' -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime.Date -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-14))} |  Remove-Item;
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
}
```

PS why not to set sleep period to 1 minute instead of 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

This excerpt is from a PowerShell script:

> .SYNOPSIS     Script to delete or list old files in a folder
>
> .DESCRIPTION   Script ***to delete files older than x-days***. The script is built ***to be used as a scheduled task***, it automatically
>   generates a logfile name based on the copy location and the current
>   date/time. There are various levels of logging available and the
>   script can also run in -listonly mode in which it only lists the files
>   it would otherwise delete. There are two main routines, one to delete
>   the files and a second routine that checks if there are any empty
>   folders left that could be deleted.

...can be found *[HERE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Delete-files-older-than-x-13b29c09)*

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code does:

1. Move all files **older than one minute, not ten,** to the specified folder
2. Sleep for one second
3. Repeat.

It never runs the second section because you're enclosing them in separate while loops. You'll need to put them in the same `while` block.